# Filter a PHP array so that only unique records remain

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP array:

```
array (size=9753)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'brand' => string 'Brand #1' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'Customer #13' (length=12)
      'total' => string '93.00' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'brand' => string 'Brand #1' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'Customer #23' (length=12)
      'total' => string '77.00' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'brand' => string 'Brand #1' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'Customer #32' (length=12)
      'total' => string '98.00' (length=5)
  ...
```

I want to filter it so that only the record with the highest `total` value remains for every unique brand (there are 100 brands, in total). The result of the operation for this sample should be:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'brand' => string 'Brand #1' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'Customer #32' (length=12)
      'total' => string '98.00' (length=5)
  ...
```

as Brand #1 has the highest `total`

This is a matter of iterating over the whole array and leaving only one record for each Brand - the one with the highest total.

I've been trying my best, but didn't manage to achieve this. The code that  I came up with is this:

```
    $c = count($ordersData);
    for($i=1; $i<$c; $i++) {
        if($ordersData[$i]['brand'] == $ordersData[$i-1]['brand'] 
            && $ordersData[$i]['total'] > $ordersData[$i-1]['total']) {
            unset($ordersData[$i-1]);
        }
    }
```

, but it does not remove all records that should be removed.

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like your best option is definitely to loop over all the records in $ordersData, as you've done. However, your logic is a bit wacky, and only compares the ordersdata total to the total of the previous order checked.

Instead, you'll likely want to start a new array, and add/overwrite values based on the brand name. Something like this, perhaps:

```
<?php

$results = array();

foreach($ordersData as $order) {
    $brand = $order['brand'];
    $total = $order['total'];

    // If an order of this brand has already been tracked
    if(array_key_exists($brand, $results)) {
        // and the total of the current order is greater than what we have recorded
        if($results[$brand]['total'] < $total) {
            // Then let's replace it!
            $results[$brand] = $order;
        }
    } else {
        // Never added this brand before? Add it then
        $results[$brand] = $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. Thank you for helping me out. On top of that, this is a good lesson, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array on total, ascending, then create a temp array indexed on brand (so that the key will get overwritten with later(higher) values), then use array_values to get numerically indexed array:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['total'] - $b['total'];
});
$temp=[];
foreach($array as $element) $temp[$element['brand']]=$element;
$out = array_values($temp);
```

Comment: unfortunatly this solution does not return correct results. The $out array suggests that the highest order value for Brand #1 is 93.00, wherese, in fact, it is 195,00.

Answer (score 0):

I've also come up with another method. I'm pasting it here just for reference (this is my initial attempt, improved).

```
    $c = count($ordersData);
    // Let's iterate through the whole array
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {            
        // Save the current brand being checked                
        $currentBrand = $ordersData[$i]['brand'];
        // If we can still check against the next record and the this is still the same brand..
        if (key_exists($i+1, $ordersData) && $ordersData[$i]['brand'] == $ordersData[$i+1]['brand']) {
            // If the next order value for the current brand is higher..
            if ( $ordersData[$i]['total'] < $ordersData[$i+1]['total'] ) {
                //Let's save/overwrite the higher order for the current brand
                $results[$currentBrand] = $ordersData[$i+1];

            }
        }                                                                            
    }
```